# Can't load requested DLL The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, gdal, geopandas, cartopy

i want to import cartopy.crs as ccrs, or just import geopandas,i keeps showing me "
Can't load requested DLL: D:\Applications\python-3.8.2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins\ogr_FileGDB.dll
126: The specified module could not be found."
but question is the DLL is right there. So what should i do?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL4jA.png)

and i have trid to change the PATH to D:\Applications\python-3.8.2\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdalplugins with double slush, and it still won't work.

Comment: i've also tried to reinstall GDAL but it doesn't matter.

Comment: I've experienced problems with the GDAL dll before. It's a notoriously annoying library to install. For me, using an anaconda environment solved it.

Comment: You might also try GIS stack exchange, as they are the GDAL experts